# What does "touch /.autorelabel" do when we reset the root password in Red Hat Enterprise Linux?

Tags: rhel

In RHEL, after we do an rd.break, and all the procedure, and do a `touch /.autorelabel`, what does the /.autorelabel do?

Comment: have you done any research to try to answer your question?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `rd.break` parameter interrupts the boot process before the control is passed over to the kernel. At this point, when you run the `passwd` command to do the password reset, the associated shadow file (`/etc/shadow`) is modified with an incorrect SELinux context.
The `touch /.autorelabel` command creates a hidden file named `.autorelabel` under the root directory. On the next boot, the SELinux subsystem will detect this file, and then relabel all of the files on that system with the correct SELinux contexts. On large disks, this process can take a good amount of time.

An alternative to the complete relabeling approach is also mentioned in the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-working_with_the_grub_2_boot_loader#sec-Changing_and_Resetting_the_Root_Password). First, use the parameters `rd.break enforcing=0` when editing the GRUB entry. This will result in the system eventually booting with SELinux set to permissive mode (warn, but do not block). Then, proceed to change the password in the same manner as before. Continue the boot process and allow the system to come up. Once it comes up, run `restorecon /etc/shadow` to restore the correct SELinux context to the `/etc/shadow` file. Then, run `setenforce 1` to re-enable SELinux and start using the system.

Comment: `rd.break` is a Dracut kernel command line option - drop to shell at the end. `rd` refers to "ramdisk"

Comment: The documentation link is 404 now :/

Comment: @NoahMay Thanks for the heads-up. I have updated the URL.